# Disqus API request to find unanswered comments from users

Tags: api, request, disqus

I'm trying to build Disqus API request to find unanswered comments from users (with time frame, for example - last 5 days).

So, response should be a posts/list with time frame (since). Question is how can I put to this request two other conditions:
- post author is not a moderator
- post doesn't have answer (reply)

I would be very grateful for help